# Problemas con llamado ajax para carácteres especiales

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Estoy haciendo llamados a mi Bd de datos que tengo almacenados, dichos datos poseen tildes, eñes, entre otros caracteres especiales, lo cual me genera en consola al ejecutar mi script esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

```html
<label class="form-label" for="Ips">IPS</label>
<Select type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="Ips" id="Ips" >
</Select>
```

JS:

```js
function cargar_ips(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../config/callips.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            let diagnosis = JSON.parse(response);
            let template = '';
            diagnosis.forEach(diagnosis => {
                template += `
                    <option value=${diagnosis.KP_UUID}>${diagnosis.Codigo}</option>
                    ` 
            });
            $('#Ips').html(template);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(cargar_ips);
```

php:

```php
<?php
    // header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"); 

    include 'config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT  PK_UUID,Name0,Nit FROM entities WHERE FK_Type = '959df8c4-1a40-11ed-8aff-846993530662' ORDER BY Name0";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if(!$result){
        die('Query Error'. mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    if ($count>0){

        $json = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $json[] = array (
                'pk_uuid' => $row['PK_UUID'],
                'name' => $row['Name0'],
                'nit' => $row['Nit']
            );
        }
        
        $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonstring;
    }
    else{
        $result = "No hay resultados";       
    }

?>
```

Comment: Cual es el response que te manda el endpoint '../config/callips.php'

Comment: Cuando el elemento no tiene ningún carácter especial, lo probé usando limit, el regresa los valores de forma correcta para el listado el problema ya viene cuando se captura con caracteres especiales/latinos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes agregar `utf8_encode` en los resultados que contengan los caracteres latinos en `PHP`, algo así por ejemplo:

```
$json = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = utf8_encode($row['Name0']);
    $json[] = array (
      'pk_uuid' => $row['PK_UUID'],
      'name' => $name,
      'nit' => $row['Nit']
    );
  }
```

Si no te funciona con `utf8_encode`, prueba con `utf8_decode`

Según la [docu de `PHP`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php): `utf8_encode` convierte la una cadena de texto de la codificación ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8.

Comment: Hola, Probé de la forma que me indicaste, pero no he obtenido resultado positivo, me regresa luego de hacer ese paso de guión en el listado todos los elementos como "undefined"

Comment: Parece que el problema del "undefined" tenía que ver con la declaración del "response", tú solución fue más que perfecta, muchas gracias.

Comment: Genial! Te animo a darle click al upvote para que sea mas fácil encontrar la respuesta a futuros visitantes.