# Almacenar y mostrar acentos

Tags: php, pdo, acentos

Tengo una BD en la que he creado las tablas con cotejamiento utf8_spanish_ci, también he probado a cambiarlo a utf8_general_ci, el caso es que si almaceno un valor en un campo que lleve acento (p.ej. "Preparación") el php me da error al recuperar el json. Si se almacena en la base de datos como (PreparaciÃ³n) se muestra correctamente.

Para intentar solucionarlo he hecho lo siguiente:

1 - Poner en el head el siguiente código:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

2 - Conexión PDO

```
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx", 'xxxx', 'xxx','charset=UTF8');
```

3 - En la respuesta del json he probado varias opciones:

```
 1- echo json_encode($respuesta);
 2- echo json_encode($respuesta,UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

No sé si se puede controlar el tema de almacenar los acentos,ñ, etc o mejor guardarlo en el otro formato y que el navegador lo interprete.

Comment: ¿eso donde te ocurre? ¿en un servidor compartido o dedicado o un localhost?  ¿de que base de datos se trata? ¿version de la base de datos?  Agrega esa información a la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: Si usas MySQL y tienes control sobre el servidor de la base de datos, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561718/cambie-mi-sistema-escrito-en-php-de-un-servidor-normal-de-hostinger-a-un-vps-de#comment993207_561718) a ver si te sirve (pero ojo, deberás probarla con datos nuevos, es decir, insertar y sacar los datos nuevos para ver si funciona, pues los datos que tengas ya almacenados quizás ya estarán corruptos)

Comment: El proyecto está alojado en un servidor compartido. La base de datos es mysql. Versión del servidor: 8.0.26 (No sé si es lo que me estabais preguntando)

Comment: Si, era eso... prueba cambiando el charset que has puesto en el PDO y en lugar de `UTF8` (que está obsoleto) pon el `utf8mb4`  (el meta déjalo como está)

Comment: Coincido con @masterguru. Otra alternativa es usar las funciones `utf8_encode` y `utf8_decode` de `php`. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/552759/problemas-con-llamado-ajax-para-car%c3%a1cteres-especiales/552765#552765) hay información que podría serte útil.

Comment: Mil gracias!!! @masterguru Era eso!!

Comment: Me alegro :-)  He puesto una respuesta para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como has confirmado en los comentarios, el problema era el **charset** utilizado en la conexión PDO.

En tu caso estabas usando la codificación `UTF-8`, que en la [documentación de mysql 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) dicen que es obsoleta, y donde recomiendan el uso de `utf8mb4` en su lugar, y en tu caso la solución ha sido esta:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx", 'xxxx', 'xxx','charset=utf8mb4');
```